# how can i make href to upper directory go up

Tags: html, dom, href

I have an html page in url: `http://localhost:63343/x/html_pages/http_failures_table/http_failures_table_agg_bl.html`

with `href`:

`<a href="../http_failures_dict/http_failures_dict_bl_0.txt">`

but when i click the url I'm directed to:

`http://localhost:63343/x/html_pages/http_failures_dict/http_failures_dict_bl_0.txt`

instead of

`http://localhost:63343/x/http_failures_dict/http_failures_dict_bl_0.txt`

how can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either go back **two** directory levels instead of one:

```
<a href="../../http_failures_dict/http_failures_dict_bl_0.txt">
```

or start from the **root**:

```
<a href="/x/http_failures_dict/http_failures_dict_bl_0.txt">
```